How to catch copy/paste events inside of a Windows application using Windows Api?
I'm currently developing an application in C++ using Windows API.
My goal is to have the app have its own clipboard - users of the app should not be able to copy (CTRL+C/CTRL+X / Right Click -> Copy/Cut) content and paste it outside of the application.
My first approach was to call AddClipboardFormatListener on the main window. However, the window received copy/paste from outside of the app (e.g. when user did CTRL+C in a different app).
Eventually, I worked it out by subclassing every control in the app and handling WM_COPY, WM_PASTE and WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE events like this:
char clipboard_data[1024];

LRESULT (*g_OldWndProc)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

LRESULT CALLBACK NewWndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT mesg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( mesg )
    {
        case WM_COPY:
            AddClipboardFormatListener(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
            if(IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT) ||
               IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT)) 
            {
                if (!OpenClipboard(nullptr)) break;

                HGLOBAL hglb = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
                if (hglb != nullptr) 
                {
                    char* lptstr = (char*) GlobalLock(hglb);
                    if (lptstr != nullptr) 
                    {
                        strcpy(clipboard_data, lptstr);
                        
                        
                    }
                    GlobalUnlock(hglb);
                }

                EmptyClipboard();
                CloseClipboard();
                RemoveClipboardFormatListener(hwnd);
            }
        break;
        case WM_PASTE:
        {
            int nStrLen = strlen(clipboard_data);
            HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, nStrLen + 1);
            char* pCopyTo = (char*) GlobalLock(hMem);
            memcpy(pCopyTo, clipboard_data, nStrLen + 1);
            GlobalUnlock(hMem);
            if(!OpenClipboard(hwnd)) break;
            SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
            CloseClipboard();
            auto status = CallWindowProc(g_OldWndProc, hwnd, mesg, wParam, lParam);
            if(!OpenClipboard(nullptr)) break;
            EmptyClipboard();
            CloseClipboard();
            if(hMem) GlobalFree(hMem);
            return status;
        }
    }

    return CallWindowProc(g_OldWndProc, hwnd, mesg, wParam, lParam);
}

I subclassed the controls like this:
g_OldWndProc = (decltype(g_OldWndProc)) SetWindowLongPtr( hSomeControl, GWLP_WNDPROC,( LONG_PTR ) NewWndProc );

(Note: I am yet to write a code that preserves what was in clipboard before copying)
That way, I am able to handle copy/paste action on UI controls I made.
However, it's a bit tedious to subclass every UI component like this.
Is there a way to do it generically?

What are you trying to accomplish here? Sounds like some sort of scuffed security concept that won't ever be.

I want to forbid users of the app from copying content (mainly text) outside of the app, so that it's harder for sensitive data to leak. It's going to be used by nontechnical people, so this approach is sufficient for me.

you probably need to start your application in a virtual machine with all external ports and devices disabled

Again, the thing I want to implement is a form of security that could be worked around, but for my use case that is really enough

Most people carry around a device in their pocket that has a camera and OCR exists.

It's going to be used under supervision. And no, they won't write it on paper either

You need to subclass the window to intercept messages. And then intercept the WM_COPY, WM_CUT, and WM_PASTE messages. In my opinion, there is no other way to do it generically.

^ This approach did not work, my WindowProc did not receive WM_COPY event when copying text from a control inside of the window

If you have low security requirements, can't you just clear the clipboard when the app is deactivated (handle WM_ACTIVATE)?

^ I guess that's the easiest approach

Yes, that's easy, but doesn't meet your requirements. Do you need easy or do you have requirements?

The ideal solution I think would be to have a clean clipboard and only fill it on pasting

I'd look at using Detours to hook the various clipboard functions for the process. Probably only SetClipboardData and GetClipboardData would be needed.

Use SetWindowsHookEx to define a message hook that intercepts messages sent to all windows in your application instead of SetWindowLongPtr.
You also need to change CallWindowProc to CallNextHookEx on your cllback function.
I think you could to collect WM_COPY, WM_CUT, and WM_PASTE events by this way.

Thank you for your answer. By using a hook I was able to collect these events and I was able to handle the copy scenario. However, when dealing with paste, calling CallNextHookEx did not cause the text to be pasted. That is problematic because I need to "clear" the clipboard right after pasting the text


I want to forbid users of the app from copying content (mainly text) outside of the app

When your clipboard listener receives notice that the clipboard has changed, check if the clipboard contains a format that you want to protect. If so, then use GetClipboardOwner() to get the HWND that put the data on the clipboard, and then use GetWindowThreadProcessId() to check if that window belongs to your process. If so, then clear the clipboard with EmptyClipboard().

Hi, thanks for the response, however, I want the user to be able to use clipboard inside of the app (if user copies content from the app, they can paste it inside the app, just not outside)

@raxonpc I doubt that's (easily) doable. If you want to prevent placing data on the clipboard unless a certain receiver asks for it would necessitate delayed rendering. However, the messages involved will not provide who the receiver is. Plus, after the contents are rendered they remain on the clipboard.

@raxonpc then you are better off implementing a private in-app clipboard instead of using the system clipboard.

Then how would you actually handle it?

@raxonpc personally, I would simply provide a separate button/menu to grab the text from a UI control and store it in memory somewhere, then have another button/menu that assigns the text from memory to a UI control. But it sounds like you don't want that.
